# Error al utilizar una variable en un if

Tags: java

Estoy creando un código donde pida dos números y luego realizar las operaciones básicas(suma, resta, multiplicación, división) con la regla que los valores introducidos por el usuario sean mayores a cero, intenté crear un if para eso, `if(variable_1 > 0)` pero al colocar la variable (en este caso la llamé variable_1) manda error, diciendo que no encuentra el símbolo: class variable_1.
No entiendo porque la variable lo toma como una clase (o eso tengo entendido).
Si me pueden ayudar a resolver este problema, gracias.

Comment: Agrega el còdigo como texto por favor ya que no se visualiza correctamente, revisa [ask], saludos.

Comment: Te comento (ya que no es código el que pones) esta fuera del `public v...` anterior que se observa; y no es error al usar la variable; lo que pasa es que el `if` lo colocaste fuera de una estructura válido (por lo antes mencionado).

Comment: el if debe encontrarse dentro del mètodo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Me temo que lo que realizas está mal, veo que estás usando un condicional fuera de tus metodos. Cosa que no es posible hacer.*

**es decir:**

```js
class Operaciones {

  if (variable_1 > 0) {
  
  }

}
```

**Esto es erroneo, lo correcto sería algo como lo siguiente:**

```js
class Operaciones {

  public void validarSentencias() {
    if (variable_1 > 0) {
      // expression
    }
  }
}
```

Espero te sirva